# Can I run a microservice which keeps a port open in the cloud?

Tags: linux, server, cloud, microservices

I'm new to microservices. I envision them as a set of processes running in two or more machines (I suppose for a given process two instances must be run in separate machines for reliability). In that setup, depending on the kind of clients I have there may be one process working as a TCP server serving on a specific high port and speaking a non-HTTP protocol.

However, for my low-bandwidth, testing purposes, I haven't found a free cloud service which provides that kind of environment (machines to run processes on – say, Java on Linux – while keeping a high port open).

Maybe the facilities I'm expecting are only available to paying customers, or maybe implementing a microservice architecture in the cloud goes beyond simply running processes in machines and sharing a database? Could someone clarify? (and if possible direct me to one such free service)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right when you say Microservices are more about independent service (processes) that can be deployed in one or more cloud machines. Each service can communicate to other using non-http protocol like Message brokers, Thrift, Remote Procedure call (RPC) etc.

As the architecture point of view, services should mostly be decoupled enough to handle complexity of distributed computing. see the image on [Microservices Architecture link](http://nordicapis.com/microservices-architecture-the-good-the-bad-and-what-you-could-be-doing-better/)
There's a concept of API Gateway which could be used for authentication and service registration and discovery purpose.

Coming back to your question, you can test microservices on single cloud (by running each service on different port) and use API Gateway to discover the service path for references here are the links which are worth to look at these.

For concept see links: [Microservices.io](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) and [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669180/microservice-service-registry-api-gateway-and-data-sharing)

For Implementation: [zookeeper](http://blog.arungupta.me/zookeeper-microservice-registration-discovery/) and [Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/13/an-introduction-to-microservices-part-2-API-gateway/) (this is what i'm using)

If you are java lover great to look at [infoQ article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Ratpack-and-Spring-Boot)
Some of the free source that might can help in building and testing microservices are: [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/microservices-on-app-engine), [hook.io](https://hook.io/examples)